# What stub means in grpc?

Tags: grpc

I'm a new user of grpc. I'm wondering what stub means in grpc. i used grpc like this.

After creating a single channel connecting the client and the server, several stubs have been created for each request.
However, when the client and server send and receive data, I understand that data is exchanged using the protobuf data type.

In general, does grpc recommend creating one stub for one channel?

I'm used grpc in my spring boot project like this.

gRpcConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class gRpcConfig{
   @Autowired
   private Enviroment gRpcInfo;
        
   @Bean(name="myChannelList")
   public ArrayList<ManagedChannel> setChannel() throws InterruptedException{
        String host1 = gRpcInfo.getProperty("Server1.host");
        Integer port1 = gRpcInfo.getProperty("Server1.port");
        String host2 = gRpcInfo.getProperty("Server2.host");
        Integer port2 = gRpcInfo.getProperty("Server2.port");

        ArrayList<ManagedChannel> channelList = new ArrayList<>();
        ManagedChannel ch = NettyChannelBuilder.forTarget(host1 + ":" port1).usePlaintext().build();
        channelList.add(ch);
        ch = NettyChannelBuilder.forTarget(host2 + ":" port2).usePlaintext().build();
        channelList.add(ch);

        return channelList;
    }
```

service.java

```
@Service
public class service{
    @Resource(name=myChannelList)
    private ArrayList<ManagedChannel> myChannelList;

    public void myService() {

         MyProtoBuf myProtoBuf = MyProtoBuf .newBuilder().setSth("").build;

         myGrpc.myFutureStub st = null;
         ArrayList<myGrpc.myFutureStub> stList = new ArrayList<>();
         for (ManagedChannel ch : myChannelList){
             /* creating stub from each channel */
             st = myGrpc.newFutureStub(ch);
             stList.add(st);
         }

         final ArrayList<myResult> resultList = new ArrayList<>();

         /* Future call for each future stub */
         for (myGrpc.myFutureStub stub : stList){
              ListenableFuture<myResult> response_future = stub.myMethod(myProtoBuf);
              Futures.addCallback(response_future , new FutureCallback<myResult>(){
                  @Oveeride
                  public void onSucess(@Nullable myResult result){
                      myResult result_future = result.getResult;
                      resultList.add(myResult);                 
                  }
                      ...
         }
    }
```

Comment: Isn't the stub for documentation purpose, giving an example how the channel is used?

Comment: I am using grpc in my spring boot project. gRpc channel information is registered and used as a bean to create a future stub for every request in my service. I have attached a code example in the text. Thanks for your reply.